# HAProxy in docker

Tags: linux, docker, haproxy

I'm trying to run haproxy on a docker, but it doesn't work.

Here's what I did:

1. Created Dockerfile that contains the following text:

```
FROM haproxy:2.3
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

2. This is my haproxy.cfg:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout client  60s
        timeout server  60s
#        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
#        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
#        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
#        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
#        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
#        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
#        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend https_in
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        bind *:443
        acl tls req.ssl_hello_type 1
        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content accept if tls
        
        acl host_server1 req.ssl_sni -i my1stdomain.com
        acl host_server2 req.ssl_sni -i my2nddomain.com

        use_backend https_Server if host_server1
        use_backend https_NUC if host_server2

backend https_Server
        mode tcp
#        option tcplog
        option ssl-hello-chk
        server Server 10.0.0.10:443

backend https_NUC
        mode tcp
#        option tcplog
        option ssl-hello-chk
        server NUC 10.0.0.40:443
```

3. The purpose is to point SSL port 443 of `my1stdomain.com` to LAN IP `10.0.0.10` and `my2nddomain.com` to IP `10.0.0.40`
4. The docker is supposed to sit on 10.0.0.44, so these are the commands I ran:

```
docker build -t my-haproxy .
```

Result:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/2 : FROM haproxy:2.3
 ---> 397cf3d55fac
Step 2/2 : COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5cc1ff3c0c6
Successfully built a5cc1ff3c0c6
Successfully tagged my-haproxy:latest
```

Then, I tested the config:

```
docker run -it --rm --name haproxy-syntax-check my-haproxy haproxy -c -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
Configuration file is valid
```

Then, I try to run it:

```
docker run -d --name haproxy --restart=always -p 10.0.0.44:443:443/tcp my-haproxy
a253dbce7341e454353e9a2b4278e22ae8172ed106aeec7
```

But, when I run `docker ps`, I see that it's not really running:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                                                                    NAMES
a253dbce7341   my-haproxy                                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Restarting (1) 12 seconds ago                                                                            haproxy
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of always restarting it, you should check the failure logs of this container. You can remove `-d` flag from your command to run this container in foreground in order to get logs on stdout:

```
docker run --name haproxy --restart=always -p 10.0.0.44:443:443/tcp my-haproxy
```

I used your `haproxy.cfg` to check the issue. I found the following two problems in the container logs:

- You are using `/var/lib/haproxy` for chroot but this directory can't be created by a non-root user. So, you can explicitly create it and change ownership to `haproxy` user.
- In `stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock` command, `/run/haproxy` directory needs to be created.

So, your Dockerfile should be updated like this to make it work:

```
FROM haproxy:2.3
RUN mkdir --parents /var/lib/haproxy && chown -R haproxy:haproxy /var/lib/haproxy
RUN mkdir /run/haproxy
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```